# Making Operating System with C++ pointer-to-member

Tags: c++, operating-system, interrupt, pointer-to-member

I'm making my own operating system with C++. But, I have a problem.
I'm programming a **Shell** class(*shell.h, shell.cc*).

1. **Commands are member functions in Shell class**

   ```
   class Shell
   {
     ...

   protected:
     // Command function list
     void clearCmd(const char*, const char*);
     void shutdownCmd(const char*, const char*);
     void dateCmd(const char*, const char*);

     ...
   };
   ```
2. **And, Shell class have a list of these commands as member variable.**

   ```
   class Shell
   {
     ...

     typedef void (Shell::*cmd_func)(const char* object_str,
                                     const char* option);
     struct Command
     {
       char keyword[MAX_KEYWORD_LEN];
       cmd_func command;
     };

     Command cmd_list[NUM_CMD + 1]; // +1 for End Of Command indicator

     ...
   };
   ```
3. **So, Shell class allocate command to cmd_list in constructor.**   <--- problem occurs here!

   ```
   Shell::Shell(Console console)
     : console_(console), input_end(0), input_at(0)
   {
     ...

     strcpy(cmd_list[0].keyword, "clear");
     strcpy(cmd_list[1].keyword, "shutdown");
     strcpy(cmd_list[2].keyword, "date");

     cmd_list[0].command = &Shell::clearCmd;
     cmd_list[1].command = &Shell::shutdownCmd;
     // cmd_list[2].command = &Shell::dateCmd;    // <- problem occurs!!

     strcpy(cmd_list[NUM_CMD].keyword, "EOL");
   }
   ```
4. **And, Shell class executes commands using pointer-to-member operator.**

   ```
   void Shell::execute()
   {
     ...

     // execute command
     (this->*(cmd_list[cmd_idx].command))(object_str, option);
   }
   ```

This code work well only when cmd_list has just two commands. The problem is occuring interrupts when third command allocated. (commented out line in 3. code)

1. No.6 interrupt **Invalid opcode** / old QEMU (ver 1.0)
2. No.7 interrupt **Device not available** / Real machine, newest QEMU (ver 2.4.1)

So, I checked GDT, IDT, TSS, PIC etc. But, I don't know what is the cause of this problem. Other interrupts work well like Divide error, timer, keyboard... **BUT! I reduced member functions to global functions, pointer-to-member to pointer-to-function, and member variable to global variable**. Then, it works! Do you know what is the cause? Can I making this shell class with C++ member function?

If you are familiar with OS and C++,
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: *I'm making my own operating system with C++* my OS teacher wishes you good luck.

Comment: Not C.  Please remove the 'C' tag.

Comment: how is void Shell::execute() called. also please read https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Making the shell functions `static` would make things easier. Is that an option?